# Download google doc to my phone and view it offline?

Tags: offline, google-drive

Is there a way for me to download google doc to my android so that I can view it off line (i.e. without data connection)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the file as a pdf and then transfer that file to the phone using something like [Awesome Drop](http://labs.dashwire.com/drop).

Then view it on the phone with a pdf reader.

Comment: so there is no normal way to download it?